# filter:drop-shadow () not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-filters, drop-shadow

I've been examining in depth the CSS `filter` property these days. I've written down some code just to make some tests. The following is a simple piece of code pertinent the `drop-shadow` filter:

**HTML**

```
<div class="rounded"></div><div class="bubble"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.rounded{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background:red;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.bubble{
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top:-40px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(50px 50px 50px 10px blue);
    filter: drop-shadow(50px 50px 10px blue);
}
```

As you can see from the attached image [filter:drop-shadow()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hR1O.jpg), it works fine in Firefox (on the right of the image) but not in Chrome (on the left of the image). I'm not interested in IE at the moment.

What could be the problem in your opinion?

Comment: You have four values in `-webkit-filter` and three in `filter`.